# Is it possible to add more than two attributes/operands in Update Expression to SET another attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to store in a column in DynamoDB table a numeric value that is the addition of other numeric columns in that table.

I read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html and while it seems to not explicitly mention that more than two operands cannot be joined with the "+" operation in a row, it does fail when I try to do so.

While I probably should not be storing in columns values that are aggregated values, and only have columns that store granular values, but is there a workaround here?

**Edit:**
Here's what I am trying to do

```
aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8042 update-item --table-name custom_table --key "{\"main_part\":{\"S\":\"hash_key\"},\"sort_part\":{\"S\":\"range_key\"}}" --update-expression "SET #A = #B + #C + :val" --expression-attribute-names "{\"#A\":\"column_1\",\"#B\":\"column_2\",\"#C\":\"column_3\"}"  --expression-attribute-values "{\":val\":{\"N\":\"10\"}}"
```

This gives the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "+", near: "#C + :val"
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the code you have that does not work?  Specifically the parameters you are using to run the UPDATE expression?  It isn't entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PeterWagener Edited my question with the aws-cli command I am using and the error I get.

Comment: What I am seeing is, the command works if it is either "#A = #B + :val" or "#A = #B + #C", that is, with only two operands.

Answer (score 0):

The docs around the [SET action of UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET) do explicitly say you can only have one two operands when using a `+` or a `-` as a part of the expression.  Notice the docs describe the `value` of the `SET` action as:

```
value ::=
    operand
    | operand '+' operand
    | operand '-' operand
```

If it supported more than two operands, you'd see it there.  Plus, your example is a great demonstration that it doesn't work.

To accomplish what (I think) you want, I think you'll need to store the interim operand as a part of the item.  Below is an example where I'm creating & updating an item to keep a count of fruit.  The item the following attributes: `greenApples`, `redApples`, `apples`, `bananas` and `fruit`.  `apples` should always be the sum of the green & red apples.  `fruit` should always be the sum of `greenApples`, `redApples`, and `bananas`.  The interesting bit of your question is how to update this item when you only know the amount you want to increase one of the component attributes.

One option to consider would be to use multiple Actions in your `UpdateItem` command, where you update both the component value (`redApples`) as well as the aggregate values (`apples` and `fruit`) in one statement.  Here's a full TypeScript code sample using [AWS SDK V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest) that does that:

```
const tableName = getFromEnv(`TABLE_NAME`);
const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const PK = `FRUIT_COUNT`;
const SK = `FRUIT_COUNT`;

interface FruitOnHand {
    bananas: number;
    greenApples: number;
    redApples: number;
}

interface FruitCount extends FruitOnHand {
    apples: number;
    fruit: number;
}

async function createItem({ bananas, greenApples, redApples }: FruitOnHand): Promise<FruitCount> {
    const apples = greenApples + redApples;
    const fruit = greenApples + redApples + bananas;
    const appleCount = { apples, fruit, greenApples, redApples, bananas };
    const item = { PK, SK, ...appleCount };
    const putCommand = new PutItemCommand({
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: marshall(item)
    });
    await client.send(putCommand);
    log(`Created item: ${inspect(item)}`);
    return appleCount;
}

async function addRedApples(toAdd: number): Promise<FruitCount> {
    const valueToAdd = { N: String(toAdd) };

    const updateCommand = new UpdateItemCommand({
        TableName: tableName,
        Key: marshall({ PK, SK }),
        UpdateExpression: `SET #APPLES = #APPLES + :val, #FRUIT = #FRUIT + :val, #RED = #RED + :val`,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#APPLES': `apples`,
            '#FRUIT': `fruit`,
            '#RED': `redApples`,
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':val': valueToAdd,
        },
        ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    });

    log(`Adding ${toAdd} red apples`)
    const { Attributes } = await client.send(updateCommand);
    const fruitCount = unmarshall(Attributes) as unknown as FruitCount;
    log(`Updated item:`, inspect(fruitCount));

    return fruitCount;
}

async function run() {
    const initial = await createItem({
        bananas: 2,
        greenApples: 5,
        redApples: 3,
    });

    assert(initial.redApples + initial.greenApples === initial.apples);
    assert(initial.fruit === initial.apples + initial.bananas);

    const updated = await addRedApples(8);
    assert(updated.redApples + updated.greenApples === updated.apples);
    assert(updated.fruit === updated.apples + updated.bananas);
}
```

A lot of that code is just setting up the example & making the TypeScript compiler happy; the interesting bit is in `addRedApples(...)` function, where I'm using this as the `UpdateExpression` ...

```
`SET #APPLES = #APPLES + :val, #FRUIT = #FRUIT + :val, #RED = #RED + :val`
```

... to increase the value of the component attribute as well as the two aggregate attributes by the same amount.

The results of executing the `run()` function show the initial and updated contents of the item:

```
Created item: {
  PK: 'FRUIT_COUNT',
  SK: 'FRUIT_COUNT',
  apples: 8,
  fruit: 10,
  greenApples: 5,
  redApples: 3,
  bananas: 2
}
Adding 8 red apples
Updated item: {
  apples: 16,
  fruit: 18,
  bananas: 2,
  SK: 'FRUIT_COUNT',
  redApples: 11,
  PK: 'FRUIT_COUNT',
  greenApples: 5
}
```

Comment: Your example has attributes that store values in incremental order. (Something the ADD operation is truly made for).
With SET, I was trying to achieve resetting of values, while still keeping the aggregation compliant.
I also tried update expressions like:
`SET column_1 = column_1 - column_2,column_2 = :val,column_1 = column_1 + :val`
and
`SET column_1 = column_1 - column_2 + :val,column_2 = :val`

But the first one failed with: `Invalid UpdateExpression: Two document paths overlap with each other; must remove or rewrite one of these paths` and the second due to more than one operation.

Comment: I was expecting a possible rule of parsing, like parsing multi-SET operations from right-to-left or left-to-right, to get executed but realised that the order is inconsequential in the expression. Found this when tried with a correct update query.

Comment: Apologies -- I don't understand the "... store values in incremental order ..." comment.  I suspect there is another solution that uses `TransactWrite`, but am unlikely to put together a fully working solution as if it were me I'd use the above.

Comment: I need to SET a column to a new value, not add to it. And so from the column that stores the sum of several columns including the one I have newly set, I'd have to subtract the old value of the column and add the new value.